# Strange behaviour of the btex..etex construct

Tags: fonts, context, metapost

I have the following code:

```
\starttext
\startMPpage
def drawtest(expr i) = %i is not used here
    draw btex dummy etex shifted (0,0);
    draw btex foo   etex shifted (1.5cm,0);
    draw btex bar   etex shifted (3cm,0);
enddef;
drawtest(5);
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

And it draws the following:

[image: example output]

What is happening here?

---

I run the code with `context thefile.tex`. The version is:

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.03
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /home/xxx/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2019.07.16 18:23
```

I reproduce the probem running this with ConTeXt live (https://live.contextgarden.net/).

Comment: I don't know what is happening, but if I put your figure inside a file named, e.g., `fig.mp`: `outputtemplate := "fig%c.mps"; beginfig(1); def drawtest(expr i) = draw btex dummy etex shifted (0,0); draw btex foo etex shifted (1.5cm,0); draw btex bar etex shifted (3cm,0); enddef; drawtest(5); endfig; end` then run `mpost fig.mp` and use LaTeX to include it: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} \includegraphics{fig1} \end{document}`, the LaTeX output is as expected: `dummy foo bar`. So, it seems to have something to do with ConTeXt or LuaTeX.

Comment: When I run this with TeX Live 2017 (ConTeXt  ver: 2017.05.15 21:48 MKIV beta, LuaTeX 1.0.4) I can't reproduce the issue, i.e., the output is _dummy foo bar_ as expected.

Comment: That's clearly a bug.  I reported it here: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/095494.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with `btex ... etex` is that these elements are processed asynchronously in ConTeXt.  The verdict from the mailing list is to use `textext` instead of `btex ... etex`.  The problem with the baseline can be resolved by using the `d` suffix where `d` stands for depth, I presume.
([Thanks Alan!](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/095497.html))

```
\starttext
\startMPpage
def drawtest(expr i) = %i is not used here
    draw textext.d("dummy") shifted (0,0);
    draw textext.d("foo")   shifted (1.5cm,0);
    draw textext.d("bar")   shifted (3cm,0);
enddef;
drawtest(5);
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

[image]